# In laravel,how can I use foreach loop?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

When I use this code:

```
Route::get('/user/{id}/posts', function ($id){
   $post = User::find($id)->postst;
   return $post;
});
```

Output is:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "user_id":1,
        "title":"Eloquent Basic Insert",
        "content":"By eloquent we can easily insert a data and it is awesome",
        "created_at":"2018-05-15 14:45:34",
        "updated_at":"2018-05-15 14:45:34",
        "deleted_at":null
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "user_id":1,
        "title":"Add with create",
        "content":"This might be fail",
        "created_at":"2018-05-15 14:47:59",
        "updated_at":"2018-05-15 14:47:59",
        "deleted_at":null
    }
]
```

But when I use foreach loop it shows only one of the array

```
 Route::get('/user/{id}/posts', function ($id){
   $post = User::find($id)->postst;
   foreach ($post as $post){
       return $post->title. '<br>';
   }
});
```

And the output for this code is:

Eloquent Basic Insert

How can I show all the title of the array on browser? and what is wrong on my code?

Comment: `return` is placed within your for loop.

Comment: Thank you...echo solve this problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is returning the title at the first loop.
You need to put your `return` out of your `foreach`:

```
Route::get('/user/{id}/posts', function ($id){
   $post = User::find($id)->postst;
   $titles = "";
   foreach ($post as $post){
       $titles .= $post->title. '<br>';
   }
   return $titles;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the return word by echo and it will be work fine

```
 Route::get('/user/{id}/posts', function ($id){
 $post = User::find($id)->postst;
  foreach ($post as $post){
   echo $post->title. '<br>';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for something different, you should be able to do something like:

```
Route::get('/user/{id}/posts', function ($id){
    $posts = User::with('posts')->find($id)->posts;
    return $posts->pluck('title');
});
```